# Designing a vectored font engine

Tags: c++, oop, opengl

I'm trying to design a vectored font engine like the one in Atari 1979. I have problem of saving the predefined character set and their co-ordinates, I don't know what is the best data-structure to save those polygons or what is the best way for to design a class for that. Here is my trial which I'm not comfortable about it at all.

```
class Character
{
public:
      Character();

public:
    int ascii;
    int strokes;
    std::vector<ci::Vec2i> points;

};
void VectorFont::Init_Chars()
{

    for (int i=0; i<1;i++)
    {
        Character char_A;
        char_A.ascii = 65;
        char_A.strokes = 6;
        ci::Vec2i point_1 = ci::Vec2i(-6,-4);
        ci::Vec2i point_2 = ci::Vec2i(0,8);
        ci::Vec2i point_3 = ci::Vec2i(0,8);
        ci::Vec2i point_4 = ci::Vec2i(6,-4);
        ci::Vec2i point_5 = ci::Vec2i(4,0);
        ci::Vec2i point_6 = ci::Vec2i(-4,0);
        char_A.points.push_back(point_1);
        char_A.points.push_back(point_2);
        char_A.points.push_back(point_3);
        char_A.points.push_back(point_4);
        char_A.points.push_back(point_5);
        char_A.points.push_back(point_6);
        chars.push_back(char_A);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these characters have holes, you will need to define a `Path` class:

```
class Path
{
     public: 
         std::vector<ci::Vec2i> points;
         int orientation; // 1 for fill, 0 for hole.
}
```

A `Path` is a collection of points and an orientation. Your paths should be closed, that is, first and last point are the same. If orientation is 1, then it means fill with black. If it's a 0, cut a hole.

Then your `Character` class would have a collection of Paths, which would be fills or holes.

The above just describes the data structure for points on fills and holes. An engine would have to be written to translate that data structure into pixels. That's another topic.

Comment: What's your opinion about my way of pushing the charachters like the way I did ?

Comment: You would still push the characters, but you would do that inside Path instead of inside VectorFont. VectorFont has Characters. A Character has Paths. A Path has Points.

Comment: but do you think its a good way to write +500 of same lines for each char ?

Comment: You will most likely not hard-code +500 lines for each char. You will most likely read data from a file to load those points, which is another major task.

Comment: My guess is that back then, there was only 1 font that came in 1 font size, per system. And so, each character was assigned a two-dimensional array that stored which pixels are on and off (so it wasn't vector-based). This information was probably stored in hardware.